# O que é uma tabela estática no SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, ssms

O que é uma tabela estática no SQL Server? Não consigo entender este conceito pelas pesquisas na internet.

Comment: Você pode mostrar o texto em que encontrou esse "conceito"? É preciso entender o contexto para responder de forma específica.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos, assim que aceitar a resposta).

Answer (score 2):

De fato é só um conceito e até onde eu sei não tem nada no SQL Server ou outro banco de dados que defina isso claramente como um mecanismo (em MySQL apenas usando MyISAM existe o termo para outra coisa completamente diferente). Uma tabela estática é aquela que não deveria ser mudada, ela é praticamente *read-only*. Não quer dizer que nunca possa ser mudada, mas isso é raro e não é feito por operações normais disponíveis para usuários. Mas reforço que tudo isso é só conceitual, nada impede de fazer diferente.

Exemplos de tabelas de tipo são cidades e estados, códigos específicos de alguma coisa que servem de descrição para algo. Muitas vezes essas tabelas são chamadas de descritivas, de referência ou *lookup*. Geralmente são muito simples, e não tem mais que um identificador e uma descrição. Elas podem ser comparadas com enumerações que alguns bancos ou linguagens possuem, mas não são tão fixas assim.